# USB keyboard not recognised

Tags: usb, keyboard

I have just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.6 Xenial Xerus (I know I am behind on this).

When the machine rebooted the wired USB (Gigabyte K6150) keyboard has no lights and I cannot type the password. The keyboard is connected to a USB3 port.

The keyboard was working before the upgrade.

Is this some kind of driver problem?

Comment: Does the keyboard work in the recovery shell?

Comment: @AndroidDev holding down the shift key when I restart does not bring up the recovery mode.